# false warning "value assigned is never read"

Tags: rust

I am getting this warning:

```
 Compiling substrate-transaction-graph v2.0.0 (/home/niko/sub/substrate/core/transaction-pool/graph)
warning: value assigned to `altered_priority` is never read
   --> core/transaction-pool/graph/src/pool.rs:137:15
    |
137 |                         let mut altered_priority=priority;
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: #[warn(unused_assignments)] on by default
    = help: maybe it is overwritten before being read?
```

On compilation of this code:

```
match self.api.validate_transaction(at, xt.clone())? {
    TransactionValidity::Valid { priority, requires, provides, longevity } => {
        info!(target: "txpool","priority before alteration: priority={:?}",priority);
        let mut altered_priority=priority;
        altered_priority=1;
        Ok(base::Transaction {
            data: xt,
            bytes,
            hash,
            priority: altered_priority,
            requires,
            provides,
            valid_till: block_number.as_().saturating_add(longevity),
         })
     },
     TransactionValidity::Invalid(e) => {
         bail!(error::Error::from(error::ErrorKind::InvalidTransaction(e)))
     },
     TransactionValidity::Unknown(e) => {
         self.listener.write().invalid(&hash);
         bail!(error::Error::from(error::ErrorKind::UnknownTransactionValidity(e)))
    },
}
```

I have added `log` messages and after dumping the variables I can confirm that they have the values that they should have (after the code is executed), i.e. the `priority` field in `Transaction` struct was indeed changed:

```
2019-05-13 21:41:17 priority before alteration: priority=107
2019-05-13 21:41:17 Map TX begins
2019-05-13 21:41:17 TX IS OK: Transaction { hash: 0x79832c9790aee4b199a046cce27e46bb7e941f38e41d25629c922c318cf7c3a2, priority: 1, valid_till: 18446744073709551615, bytes: 107, requires: [], provides: [d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d0200000000000000], data: 81ffd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27df063b12602c33fa92df4895ab3ecd9f2ad72544bd4b55f1c6c91c8c107dba3654fd13ca5e81612a7fe011414ca604e8f99feb1ed35ce471361ee2c14defdc503080003000ca10f}
2019-05-13 21:41:17 TX priority: 1
2019-05-13 21:41:17 Ok(Transaction { hash: 0x79832c9790aee4b199a046cce27e46bb7e941f38e41d25629c922c318cf7c3a2, priority: 1, valid_till: 18446744073709551615, bytes: 107, requires: [], provides: [d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d0200000000000000], data: 81ffd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27df063b12602c33fa92df4895ab3ecd9f2ad72544bd4b55f1c6c91c8c107dba3654fd13ca5e81612a7fe011414ca604e8f99feb1ed35ce471361ee2c14defdc503080003000ca10f})
2019-05-13 21:41:17 Map TX ends
```

Actually, without even dumping the values, it is obvious from the code itself that the value is used in the creation of the struct `Transaction`.
So, is this a bug in `Rust` ?

Comment: @ArekBulski I didn’t downvote, but I would speculate that the downvoters don’t appreciate the questioner’s immediate leap to “false warning” and “bug in Rust”, when the value really is unused, the problem is in the input code, and the compiler’s warning is correct, clear, and helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You wrote `let mut altered_priority = priority;` followed immediately by `altered_priority = 1;`.  The compiler is warning you that the initial value `priority` you assigned to `altered_priority` in the first of these two statements is never read.  It is correct: the only value ever read from the `altered_priority` variable is `1`, not `priority`.

There’s no reason to write one value and then immediately and unconditionally replace it with another.  You could have replaced those two statements with simply `let altered_priority = 1;`.  (Or you could get rid of the variable and write `priority: 1` instead of `priority: altered_priority` below.)

Comment: no, there is a reason of having `let mut altered_priority = priority` , I am copying the type from `priority` since I don't know what type it is, so to avoid digging into the code, I just copy the value together with the type

Comment: again: why aren't you just using `1` instead of `altered_priority`?

Comment: It would get converted into the needed type, just the same way it is with the variable.